# PHP displays 'Not found" message before input to form

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

My PHP/SQL code displays the "Not found" message before anything is input to the HTML form and before the SQL search, ie when the page opens:

Not Found message
[image]

Otherwise the code works fine, finds the correct record for the input and displays it, and displays the "Not found" message when the search returns no matching records.

How can I suppress the "Not found" message until the SQL is executed?

Here's the SQL part of the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT order_no, name, order_date FROM test1 WHERE order_no = $order_no";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Order #: " . $row["order_no"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["order_date"]. "<br>";

    }  
} else  
  echo "Not found";
```

Comment: You need to test to make sure your form is submitted before you run your PHP code. Usually most people test for the submit button being clicked.

Comment: presumably `$order_no` is derived from the form submission?

Comment: Remember the form is not submitted (and therefore no `$_POST/$_GET` variables exist) when you run the page from a link or a manually entered url or redirect

Comment: And you need to show a bit more of the relevant code in your next question

Comment: You could use Javascript to hide it until the button is clicked

Comment: Why would you do that @mike510a?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  OP said `how to suppress the "Not Found" messag\e until SQL is executed`  which I'm assuming is for looks not functionality, ergo simply hiding the div should work too?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't check for a submitted form your `php` code will always be executed.

Something like this should work (depending whether you are using a `POST` or `GET` request:

```
if (isset($_POST['your_var']) || isset($_GET['your_var'])) {
    echo "Here you can place the code you posted.";
}
```

Comment: with $_REQUEST you check both $_POST and $_GET